# C++ multimap<int, vector<string>> memory allocation issue

Tags: c++, string, vector, multimap

I am wondering how to resolve this problem where the vectors (vec, vec2) are destroyed after exiting storeData(), which causes a segmentation fault in main().
Should I allocate memories for each vector (vec, vec2)? If so, which is the best way to do it?
Also, how could I delete them after?
Thank you.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void storeData();

multimap<int, vector<string> > mypairs;

void storeData()
{
    vector<string> vec;
    vec.push_back("one");
    vec.push_back("two");

    vector<string> vec2;
    vec2.push_back("alpha");
    vec2.push_back("beta");

    mypairs.insert(make_pair(1, vec));
    mypairs.insert(make_pair(2, vec2));
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    storeData();

    string str;
    vector<string>::const_iterator it;
    multimap<int, vector<string> >::const_iterator res;
    res = mypairs.find(1);
    for(it = res->second.begin(); it < res->second.end(); it++) {
        str = *it;
    }
    //use string str to do something else later...
}
```

Comment: I don't see any memory issues in this code snippet. Perhaps the problem is elsewhere in your code?

Comment: This program does not segfault with GCC 4.7.2

Comment: You should check the iterator returned from `mypairs.find(1)` in case it returns an `end()` iterator. It works in this instance so the problem isn't in the code you've shown, just like when you asked this question yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

`vec` and `vec2` will be copied into `mypairs`, so it doesn't matter if the original objects are destroyed.

You should post more information about the segfault.

Comment: iterator insert(const value_type& x), would insert just send the reference to mypairs instead?

Comment: @user3097451 standard library containers hold values not references. The function just takes it by reference to avoid unnecessary copies. Also the parameter is a const reference so if it did insert just the reference you would never be able to modify it since it's const.

Comment: @DavidBrown is there a way to reuse the strings inside the vector then?

Comment: @user3097451 what do you mean by reuse and which strings in which vector? It would be helpful if you posted some code which exhibits the problem you're having as the code you've posted seems fine.